# Serverside latency in Azure Cosmos MongoDB is high for bulk writes

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to bulk insert 1000 records into my cosmos DB (Mongo API). I am using Mongo ruby client library and using "insert_many" function to insert the bulk data. The server side latency is coming to be around 5-10 seconds per 1000 record insert which is very huge. What am I doing wrong? Attaching the Server-Side latency metric image

At 9.50pm, the insert operation was performed and it took around 5s.
[image]

At 9.50pm, the RU consumption is only 30%
[image]

Code snippet:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('<connection_string>', :database => 'user-groups')
collection = client[:mapping]

data = []
1..1000.times do |i|
    data << {
        user_id: "#{i}user",
        group_id: "#{i}group",
        tenant_id: "1"
    }
    
end
collection.insert_many(data)
```

There are no indexing present for the collection

Comment: Please edit to show relevant code, indexing details, RU throttling evidence (or lack of evidence), etc. As written, you're only going to get opinions and guesses, since there's nothing aside from a graph.

Comment: Not enough information here to answer. How much throughput do you have provisioned? Is this dedicated collection throughput or shared database throughput? Is this a sharded collection? What is the shard key? Are your inserts all using the same shard key? Is your app in the same region as the collection in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The ordered parameter was causing the latency issue here. By default the ordered paramater is true which makes sure the records are getting inserted in ordered fashion.

Fix:

```
collection.insert_many(data, { ordered: false })
```

On specifying the ordered parameter as false, it will make sure that the records are not inserted in the order which improved the performance the great extend.